# Django message display and wrong loop problem

Tags: python, html

When I was using Django to try to make a user login, registration and logout interface, I encountered a problem. I used Django's built-in message to try to send login status information to the user (similar to: Welcome user xx, logged in, password errors and the like), unfortunately, not only did my message not get output, the original initial web page also turned into a weird login success interface. Since I am a newbie, the description may not be accurate, but the code is here, I hope there is Good Samaritans were able to solve my problem, long live the geeks!

This is index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>      <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>身份验证</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
        {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <strong>提示：</strong> {{ message }}
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}

        <h3>欢迎使用应用程序！</h3>

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <h3>hello,{{ username }}</h3>
        <h4>你已成功进入程序！</h4>
        <button type="submit"><a href="/signout">注销</a></button>

        {% else %}
        <button type="submit"><a href="/signup">注册</a></button>
        <button type="submit"><a href="/signin">登录</a></button>
        {% endif %}
        <script src="" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    return render(request,"success/index.html")

def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        realname = request.POST['realname']
        email = request.POST['email']
        pass1 = request.POST['pass1']
        pass2 = request.POST['pass2']

        myuser = User.objects.create_user(username,email,pass1)
        myuser.real_name = realname

        myuser.save()

        messages.success(request,"注册成功！")
        return redirect('登录')

    return render(request,"success/signup.html")

def signin(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' :
        username = request.POST['username']
        pass1 = request.POST['pass1']

        user = authenticate(username = username,password = pass1)

        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            username = user.username
            return render(request,"success/index.html",{'username':username})

        else:
            messages.error(request,"账号不存在或密码错误！")
            return redirect('主页')

    return render(request,"success/signin.html")

def signout(request):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue is that the messages are not being displayed on the page and the page is being redirected to a different view.

use the messages.add_message() method.

```
from django.contrib import messages

def signin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        pass1 = request.POST['pass1']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=pass1)

        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, f"Welcome {user.username}, you have successfully logged in!")
            return redirect('home')

        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid username or password.")
            return redirect('signin')

    return render(request, "success/signin.html")
```

And add this line to your **context_processors** on **settings.py**

```
'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
```

And **MIDDLEWARE**

```
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
```

Comment: ok I succeeded! Thank you very much. I just put it in the wrong place. If it doesn't take up your time, I would like to know the principle of this, because I followed other tutorials. I don't know if it is because of version changes or other reasons. In short, Thank you very much!

Comment: If it is help you , mark as if is correct.which one you want to know ?

Comment: I want to know the specific use of the two lines of code you wrote in setting.py, because I didn't notice it before, and some tutorials didn't mention it.(:

Comment: 'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages' in the settings.py file is a context processor that adds the messages framework to the context of every rendered template. Context processors are functions that take a request object as an argument and return a dictionary of items that get merged into the context. The context gets rendered to your template as per your view and it attaches whatever else your context processors merge in.

Comment: 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware' in the MIDDLEWARE setting is a middleware that provides support for cookie- and session-based message storage. Middleware is a framework of hooks into Django's request/response processing.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are the best programmer I have seen this year!

Comment: Nope . But I am trying 

Comment: I posted a new question. If it is convenient for you, can you come and take a look? thank you very much!